# Converting a string of numbers from Scanner to integers using loop?

Tags: java

Have an assignment that requires me to take an input from the user of a series of numbers. ex.(1 12 -34 9) I am then asked to determine the number of positive and negative numbers. The class has not gotten into any of the "easy" solutions to this problem such as arrays, string.split(), buffers etc... The most advanced methods taught are the use of loops. My question is how can I take the string line of numbers and separate them individually without the aforementioned methods? I can take it the rest of the way I am certain without complications but this one step has me at a loss. Any input will help. Thanks

Comment: Share your efforts (code) to resolve the problem in hand.

Comment: Read the javadoc of Scanner, to understand how it works, and how to read integers using one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has come to my attention that the confusing way in which the assignment is worded combined with the misleading example of the running program led me to believe the numbers were entered all at once when in reality the numbers are to be prompted for one at a time. I can easily write the program that handles THIS method. Thanks to all of the responses and I apologize for a question that leads to nowhere. Just so you don't think I am crazy here is the "example" of the program running as it should provided in the assignment:

Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: 1 2 -1 3 0

The number of positives is 3

The number of negatives is 1

Notice how the input looks as though it is a one line entry -_-

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you start with a string containing all the numbers - I'll call it numString.
Then:

```
    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    String aNumber = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numString.length(); i++){
        String letter = numString.substring(i, i+1);
        if (letter.equals(" ")){
            numbers.add(aNumber);
            aNumber = "";
        }
        else{
            aNumber += letter;
        }
     }
    ArrayList<String> negatives = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> positives = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : numbers){
        if(s.contains("-")){
            negatives.add(s);
        }else{
            positives.add(s);
    }
    System.out.println("There were " + positives.size() + "positive numbers.");
    System.out.println("There were " + negatives.size() + "negative numbers.");
    System.out.println("Making a total of " + numbers.size() + "numbers.");
```

Of course, I'd only recommend this solution in the context of what you've learned. This wouldn't be the best way to do this otherwise.
Good luck!

edit - Alternatively - quicker but more logically complex option:
There should be as many "-" as negative numbers, and one less space than total numbers - and as many positive numbers as totalCount minus negativeCount.
So in pseudocode:

NegativesCount = count("-");

PositivesCount = count(" ") + 1 - NegativesCount;

and in code:

```
    int dashCount = 0;
    int spaceCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numString.length(); i++){
        String letter = numString.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (letter.equals(" ")){
            spaceCount++;
        }
        else if(letter.equals("-")){
            dashCount++;
        }
    }
    int negCount = dashCount;
    int posCount = spaceCount - 1 + dashCount;
    System.out.println("There were " + posCount + "positive numbers.");
    System.out.println("There were " + negCount + "negative numbers.");
    System.out.println("Making a total of " + spaceCount + "numbers.");
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is by using regex.

You can count the instance of  followed by -ve sign to count number of negative integers. and  count instance of  followed by numerical value to count number of positive integers.